# Can i NAT 2 ports to same internal port?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a streaming camera, can i reach port 80 of the camera from two different ports?

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10079 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.8.41:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.8.41:80
```

Comment: I don't see why not, have you tried it? If so and it doesn't work explain what you've tried and how you've tried to debug it (e.g. wireshark)

Comment: instead of nat, use nginx as reverse proxy